# Test version of GWT DOM

Tags: unit-testing, gwt

Does anybody know any libraries which allow to create GWT DOM tree without having a browser running. I need this for fast test. It seems to me that DOM classes contain a lot of native methods, which are almost impossible to mock.

Answer (score 0):

[Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) may be suitable for your task. It runs WebKit in memory without any graphical interface so it works much faster then the "normal" browser.

Comment: PhantomJS won't be suitable for GWT for the use case described. To be fast, tests should be run in JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Searching other stuff on internet I found it. I have no idea if it works for you, if yes, share your experience because your topic is useful:

https://github.com/gwt-test-utils/gwt-test-utils/wiki/Browser-simulation